# Is it possible initialize a C's function pointer with a function declaration in the same line?

Tags: c, initialization, function-pointers, function-declaration

I wondered if it is possible to initialize a function pointer in C with the declaration of a function without the need to declare it previously.

Doing something like this:

```
FunctionPointer my_pointer = void MyFunction() {};
```

I know that likely you should do something like this:

```
void MyFunction() {}

my_pointer = MyFunction;
```

But I was interested to know if the compact's one is possible in some way.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. You may not use a declaration as an initializer because the initializer must be an expression.